# Check status of sent text message on textlocal

Tags: php

I am using text local (textlocal.com) to send text messages using PHP, here is the code i have to send the messages:

```
// Send the POST request with cURL
$ch = curl_init('https://www.txtlocal.com/sendsmspost.php'); //note https for SSL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch); //This is the result from Textlocal
curl_close($ch);
```

how can i check if it has failed or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$resultStatus = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ($resultStatus != 200) {
        die('Request failed: HTTP status code: ' . $resultStatus);
    }
```

or

```
 var_dump($result );
```

refer [Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php)